# how can I save the last cursor and then call it back in tweepy so that I can get huge number of follower_ids in a script that has multiple thread

Tags: python, oop, web-scraping, cursor, tweepy

I have a task to make a scraper that get the name of the followers of certain username
to maximize the output my goal was to get the followers ids then for each ids I will get the name in a text file (since get_follower_ids give me a maxmimum of 75000 ids per 15 min (15 requests * 5000 counts) and I can get about 90k name also (900 request of api.get_user * count = 100)
the code will be 2 functions one for ids

```
name = input('Please Enter username:')
finished = False
user_followers = []
finished = []

def get_ids(num = page_num):

        for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.get_follower_ids, screen_name=name,count = 5000).pages(num):
            user_followers.extend(page)
            num = num+1
        finished.append('True')
```

and one for username that will run asynchronously with thread this function will run forever until the first one finished and it won't call a request the number of users name not less than the number of ids

```
    def get_names():
        users_name = []
        print(1)
        while True:
            if len(users_name) < len(user_followers):
                for users in range(0,len(user_followers)):
                    user_objs = api.lookup_users(user_id=user_followers[len(users_name):len(users_name) + 100])
                    for name in user_objs:
                        users_name.append(name.screen_name)
                with open('{}.txt'.format(name), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                    for user_name in users_name:
                        f.write(user_name) + f.write('\n')
                print(len(users_name))
                print(len(user_followers))
                try:
                    print(finished[0])
                    if finished[0] == 'True' and len(users_name) == len(user_followers):
                        print(users_name)
                        break
                except:
                    pass
```

lastly I made each function on thread so they will run parallel

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=get_ids)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=get_names)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

now this works fine without any error even in large data except that I can't close it untill it finish otherwise it will begin from the start I have searched here and on github that I need to save the Cursor for the next time I don't know how I have made this code

```
tweepy_cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.get_follower_ids, screen_name='DemonsNFT', count=5000).pages()
i = 0
while True:
    try:
        page = tweepy_cursor.next()
        cursor = tweepy_cursor.next_cursor
        for follower in page:
            user_followers.append(follower)
        print(cursor)
        print(type(cursor))
    except:
        break
print(len(set(user_followers)))
```

this print the cursor but I think it's nor correct as the ouput is integer not object and it changes every time so is this normal if so how to use the last cursor to begin with?if not is there a way I can use to save the cursor so I can begin from it the next time